# What is the rank in each of the following case?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

The columns of $A$ are $n$ vectors from $R^m$. If they are linearly independent, what is the rank of $A$? If they span $R^m$, what is the rank? If they are a basis for $R^m$ what then?

Here's my explanation:
The $n$ vectors are linearly independent, so $rank(A)=n$.
Now comes my confusion, to span $R^m$, I need $m$ vectors, so $rank(A)=m=n$. 
Same condition to be a  basis of $R^m$. Am I correct?

Comment: "*If they are linearly independent, what is the rank*"  was the first question.  My interpretation of the next sentence "*If they span $\Bbb R^m$, what is the rank*" is that we have removed the hypothesis in the previous sentence and are working with a new set of hypotheses now.  In the second question, that is to say, I do not think that the $n$ vectors are necessarily independent any more.

Comment: If you were to interpret the second question as "If the vectors are linearly independent *and* they span $\Bbb R^m$, what is the rank" then you are correct, it will be that $\text{rank}(A)=m=n$.  Similarly for if the columns form a basis for $\Bbb R^m$ (*which requires the columns be linearly independent and span $\Bbb R^m$, giving more reason to think that my original interpretation is the correct one, afterall why ask the same question twice in a row?*)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. So we need at least $m$ vectors to span $R^m$, hence every row must have a pivot element. So $rank(A)=m$. This is right?

Comment: Wouldn't rank(A) be <= n? You do not need to span(R^m) to be linearly independent?

Comment: @RonJensen $rank(A)\leq \text{min}(m,n)$ always.  Knowing column independence implies that it is $n$.  Knowing it spans implies that it is $m$.  Knowing that it is both implies that $n$ and $m$ are equal and that the rank is $n$ and $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Note that if the columns of $A$ are $n$ linerly independent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^m$ than $n\le m$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is considering the fact that in the second question, the vectors are still linearly independent. But as suggested above, if these are separate questions in themselves, then for the second question, rank=m. Am I correct? (Please read the comments above).

Comment: If the $n$ columns are lineraly independent and span $\mathbb{R}^n$ than they are a basis and $n=m$. So, yes, the questions are redundant.